# List passed to join doesn't produce the correct output

Tags: string, tcl

I collect some information using the following method:

```
proc getJobinfo {question} {
    puts -nonewline "$question: "
    flush stdout
    gets stdin answer
    set cleanedanswer [string trim [::textutil::string::capEachWord $answer]]
    if {$cleanedanswer eq ""} {
       throw {Value Empty} {Input cannot be empty!}
    }
    return $cleanedanswer
}
```

and capture the result like this:

```
set systemTime [clock seconds]
set yearmonthday [clock format $systemTime -format %Y%m%d-%H%M%S]

set company_name [getJobinfo "Company Name"]
set position [getJobinfo "Position"]
```

I need to add it to a list so that I can join it to create a path.

Following the [`join`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/join.htm) documentation I tried this:

```
set submission_path [join {$company_name $position $yearmonthday} "\\"]
```

Suppose I answered with `Microsoft` and `Software Engineer` as the input, I expected to get:

```
Microsoft\Software Engineer\20200509-1108
```

Instead I get:

```
$company_name\$position\yearmonthday
```

Can someone elaborate on why? and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this a file pathname you're making? If so, please use `file join` and possibly `file nativename` afterwards. (If you're not making a filename, then use the answer below.)

Comment: @DonalFellows - You're correct, and I did find `file join` in the docs and used it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only coming down to [quoting](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Quoting). So essentially what you should do instead is to use something that's not braces because you want to allow for variable substitution:

```
set submission_path [join "$company_name $position $yearmonthday" "\\"]
```

The above works, but the recommended way to do it in this case, since you're effectively joining a list, is to use the list command:

```
set submission_path [join [list $company_name $position $yearmonthday] "\\"]
```

Comment: Don't use the quoted version: it will convert *all* spaces to backslashes: `Microsoft\Software\Engineer\...` -- use `list`