# Associated array with list in tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm beginner in TCL scripting and I'm trying to store list as part of associated array as below.

**script:**

```
set cellno 0
set red redcolor
set green greencolor
set blue bluecolor

set myVariable($cellno) {$red $green $blue}

puts [lindex $myVariable($cellno) 2]
```

**problem:**

For some reason `puts [lindex $myVariable($cellno) 2]` is displaying value as below

```
 $blue
```

Instead of

```
 bluecolor
```

Comment: Braces won't do variable substitution in Tcl. Try with double quotes as `set myVariable($cellno) "$red $green $blue"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List passed to join doesn't produce the correct output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699000/list-passed-to-join-doesnt-produce-the-correct-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
set myVariable($cellno) {$red $green $blue}
```

...does not substitute the color variables since they are in braces. You could use double quotes:

```
set myVariable($cellno) "$red $green $blue"
```

Since you use it as a list using `lindex`, prefer `list` to avoid unintentional word splitting (and merging in case of empty string or whitespace only variables):

```
set myVariable($cellno) [list $red $green $blue]
```

Comment: Using `list` like that allows Tcl to use a more efficient implementation than using double quotes.